# datastax opscenter installation failed with 'no such option: --post-install' error

Tags: python, opscenter

Background: 
I have a 3 node cassandra (1.2.5) cluster and I am trying to install datastax on one of the nodes. I am following instructions from: http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/install/install_deb
I have following already installed:
java -version = 1.6.0_24
python -V = 2.6.6
openssl version = 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

Issue: 
When I run 'sudo apt-get install opscenter-free', the installation starts but errors out with:
update-python-modules: error: no such option: --post-install
dpkg: error processing opscenter-free (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 2

Possible root cause:
By searching for error I could gather it looks like python issue. 
I ran ls to see where python resides, here some results:
ls /usr/local/bin = python python2.6 python2.7
ls /usr/bin/ = python python2.5
As specified before if I run 'python -V' result is 2.6.6.
I don't understand how to make my opscenter installer to look at the appropriate version?
or how to understand which python it is referring to?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an issue with the following from the opscenter-free package:

```
# cause any deferred python module compilation (like for telephus) to be done
# now, before the initscript starts
if which update-python-modules >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    update-python-modules --post-install
fi
```

update-python-modules comes with the python-support package.  It looks like the binary is available, but whatever version the install process is finding doesn't recognize the `--post-install` option.

If `which update-python-modules` points to an older (<= 2.5) or newer (3.0+) version of the script, you can try removing whatever package is including that, or updating the python-support package.